# Dynamic Accordion Repetitive Code

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, accordion

I have built a navigation page in an accordion format using mysqli and php. You can see an example at 
  [1]: http://www.outerhebridesalgae.uk/marine/marine-taxononic-list.php/ "Marine Algae".
This works perfectly well, but the coding is very repetitive as I am repeating the same code for each heading in the accordion. This is fine for a limited number of headings, but some of my tables have 30 or more headings! Is there a more efficient approach? Thank you for your assistance.

A sample of the code follows:

```
<?phprequire '../assets/includes/conn.inc.php';
    $query1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM marine WHERE famid='1' ORDER BY marine.species");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
    $totalRows_query1 = mysqli_num_rows($query1);

    $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM marine WHERE famid='2' ORDER BY marine.species");
    $row2= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
    $totalRows_query2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

    $query4 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM marine WHERE famid='4' ORDER BY marine.species");
    $row4= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4);
    $totalRows_query4 = mysqli_num_rows($query4);
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>.......</head>
    <body>

<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-margin">
        <h2 class="uk-panel-title">Chlorophyta - Green Seaweeds</h2>
        <div id="firstpane" class="msg_list">
          <p class="msg_head"> <?php echo $row1['family']; ?><img src="../images/arrow.jpg" alt="arrow open"  align="right"></p>
          <div class="msg_body">
            <table width="100%" >
              <?php do { ?>
              <tr>
                <td id="marine.species"><a href="marine-species.php?id=<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['species']; ?></a></td>
                <?php } while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)); ?>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <p class="msg_head"><?php echo $row2['family']; ?><img src="../images/arrow.jpg" alt="arrow open"  align="right"></p>
          <div class="msg_body">
            <table width="100%" >
              <?php do { ?>
              <tr>
                <td id="marine.species"><a href="marine-species.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row2['species']; ?></a></td>
                <?php } while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)); ?>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <p class="msg_head"><?php echo $row4['family']; ?><img src="../images/arrow.jpg" alt="arrow open"  align="right"></p>
          <div class="msg_body">
            <table width="100%" >
              <?php do { ?>
              <tr>
                <td id="marine.species"><a href="marine-species.php?id=<?php   echo $row4['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row4['species']; ?></a></td>
                <?php } while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4)); ?>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div></body></html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ADyson In it's current form, it doesn't belong at Code Review at all.

Comment: @ADyson 1) Questions should be closed if they're off-topic HERE. Regardless of what else exists on the network. Think of a reason why it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow regardless of Code Review. 2) The posted code is a sample lacking the context required for database questions (at least an overview of the schema should be inserted). I'm not sure the data hasn't been exemplified either, which could be a problem. 3) Efficient can mean anything. Is OP running out of RAM? Returning too much data to the client? Should it be faster CPU-wise?

Comment: @Mast I'd say it was off-topic here because there's nothing to fix, there's no specific problem with the code other than the OP wants to refactor it a bit. OP hasn't reported any issues running the code (e.g. performance), they just want it to be less repetitive. It strikes me as a better fit for CodeReview - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - "looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…

Best practices and design pattern usage". Seems like pretty much what is being asked, no? Probably more detail could be added, though

Comment: @ADyson then vote to close as off-topic because it's unclear or too broad, not *because it belongs on [codereview.se]* =)

Comment: Apologies - a misunderstanding of where I should have posted my question.